# Как изменить цвет подсветки для текста в кавычках в PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Ввожу командлет, агрумент которого содержит строку, например:

```
Set-Location "C:\TEMP"
```

Подсветка текста в кавычках при вводе подсвечивается цветом. Как поменять цвет подсветки?

Comment: https://4sysops.com/wiki/change-powershell-console-syntax-highlighting-colors-of-psreadline/

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За подсветку синтаксиса отвечает модуль **PSReadLine**. Чтобы изменить цвет необходимо ввести команду:

```sh
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind String -BackgroundColor DarkRed
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind String -ForegroundColor White
```

Команда присвоит **ТёмноКрасный** цвет для фона строк и **Белый** для самого текста строки - того что в кавычках.

Список элементов для подсветки получить можно так:

```sh
Get-PSReadlineOption | Select *color
```

Выведет примерно следующее:

```
ContinuationPromptForegroundColor : DarkYellow
ContinuationPromptBackgroundColor : DarkMagenta
DefaultTokenForegroundColor       : DarkYellow
CommentForegroundColor            : DarkGreen
KeywordForegroundColor            : Green
StringForegroundColor             : DarkCyan
OperatorForegroundColor           : DarkGray
...
```

Постфиксы `ForegroundColor` и `BackgroundColor` отбрасываем. Чтобы получить командлет для изменения подсветки элемента "строки": ищем элемент в списке `String…`  . Подставляем имя команды в выражение:
`Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind $element -BackgroundColor DarkRed`